# Why System class cannot be instantiated

Tags: java

Despite System is a concrete class, it cannot be instantiated.

> test.java:4: System() has private access in java.lang.System

I know it's not allowed to create object. Question is why....?

Comment: Why would you want to create an instance of the system class?

Comment: I just want to know why it is forbidden from users to create an object of that class. The logical reason for it.

Comment: The real question that you should be asking is: in what possible scenario could require an instance of the System class.

Comment: @JordanWhite yes. That was what i meant. Sorry for the misleading Question...:-(

Comment: In that case the answer is there isn't one. All the functionality of the System class is static.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

because there's no reason to instantiate it.  That's not what it's for.

all it is, is a bunch of static methods and properties.

Answer (score 14):

It cannot be instantiated because it has got a private constructor.

Comment: i know it's a private constructor. Error is explanatory enough. I want to know why is it private. The motive behind it

Comment: @prime It's private because there is no point to have an instance of it.

Comment: @prime, it doesn't change the fact that "constructor is private" is the simplest correct answer for this question :D

Comment: @prime because there is only one `System`. Instantiating multiple copies of `System` wouldn't make any sense given the context of the class - providing a bunch of static methods.

Comment: They put all the functionality you need in static methods and variables so no instance is necessary... It should also be noted that the System class is Final so there can be no subclassing as well.

Comment: that's what it is designed for.

Comment: I know the asker wanted the motivation, but this is the answer that I'm here for.